# faceapi.js nodejs + express implementation

Tags: node.js, express, face-recognition

I am trying to develop a real time face recognition model using faceapi js using node and express. I have tried to recognize the face using the below code.

https://gist.github.com/Dannybrown2710/5e30c063da936ee947d8fff474f9f57b

But it seems that it takes a minute to train and recognize a model. Is there any way to improve recognizing speed to get real time results as in browser?

Answer (score 0):

The code is loading and training the models on each request, why not load once on startup like so:

```
let loadModelsPromise = loadModels();

async function detectFace(image) {
    await loadModelsPromise;

    ...
```

This way the first call may be delayed, however each subsequent call should be very quick. I'm presuming that the uploaded face is not added to the training data.

Comment: How to optimize the training data?